# Get value from form containing dynamically created name

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a Project for school but i don't seem to be able to figure this out:
I want that the array matArray contains the data gotten out of the form, but when you go on the site and add a new element (through button) a new `div` is created which every time has a new name (`nameMat.value = "mat" + realNumber;`) and i want to be able to get them. Does anybody know how i can do this?

Code:

```js
let realNumber = 1;

function handleAddMat() {
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  var mat = document.createElement("DIV");
  nameMat = document.createAttribute("name");
  nameMat.value = "mat" + realNumber;
  idMat = document.createAttribute("id");
  idMat.value = "mat" + realNumber;
  mat.setAttributeNode(nameMat);
  mat.setAttributeNode(idMat);
  var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
  var nameMatNode = document.createTextNode("Name Material: ");
  var input1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var input1Type = document.createAttribute("type");
  input1Type.value = "text";
  var input1Name = document.createAttribute("name");
  input1Name.value = "matName";
  input1.setAttributeNode(input1Type);
  input1.setAttributeNode(input1Name);
  label.appendChild(nameMatNode);
  mat.appendChild(label);
  mat.appendChild(input1);
  mat.appendChild(br);
  var br1 = document.createElement("br");
  var label1 = document.createElement("label");
  var anzMatNode = document.createTextNode("Anzahl Material: ");
  var input2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var input2Type = document.createAttribute("type");
  input2Type.value = "number";
  var input2Name = document.createAttribute("name");
  input2Name.value = "matAnz";
  input2.setAttributeNode(input2Type);
  input2.setAttributeNode(input2Name);
  label1.appendChild(anzMatNode);
  mat.appendChild(label1);
  mat.appendChild(input2);
  mat.appendChild(br1);
  var br2 = document.createElement("br");
  var br3 = document.createElement("br");
  var label2 = document.createElement("label");
  var preisMatNode = document.createTextNode("Preis pro stück Material(in CHF): ")
  var input3 = document.createElement("INPUT");
  var input3Type = document.createAttribute("type");
  input3Type.value = "number";
  var input3Name = document.createAttribute("name");
  input3Name.value = "matPreis";
  input3.setAttributeNode(input3Type);
  input3.setAttributeNode(input3Name);
  label2.appendChild(preisMatNode);
  mat.appendChild(label2);
  mat.appendChild(input3);
  mat.appendChild(br2);
  mat.appendChild(br3);
  document.getElementById("mat").appendChild(mat);
  ++realNumber;
  console.log(realNumber);
}

function handleSubmit() {
  const matArray = [];
  for (i = 1; i < realNumber; i++) {
    var id = "mat" + i;
    const matNameArray = ['document', 'form', id, 'matName', 'value']
    const matAnzArray = ["document", "form", id, "matAnz", "value"]
    const matPreisArray = ['document', 'form', id, 'matPreis', 'value']
    var preMatName = matNameArray.join(".");
    var preMatAnz = matAnzArray.join(".");
    var preMatPreis = matPreisArray.join(".");
    var matName = preMatName;
    var matAnz = preMatAnz;
    var matPreis = preMatPreis;
    matArray.push(matName);
    matArray.push(matAnz);
    matArray.push(matPreis);
  }
  console.log(matArray);
  var zeit = parseFloat(document.form.zeit.value);
  var strecke = parseFloat(document.form.strecke.value);
  var lastMatName = parseFloat(document.form.mat.matName.value);
  var lastMatAnz = parseFloat(document.form.mat.matAnz.value);
  var lastMatPreis = parseFloat(document.form.mat.matPreis.value);
  console.log("Zeit: " + zeit + ", Strecke: " + strecke + ", matName: " + lastMatName + ", matAnz: " + lastMatAnz + ", matPreis: " + lastMatPreis)
  console.log(getElementByVar(id));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>IT-Support</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form" method="dialog">
    <label for="zeit">Benötigte Zeit (in h): </label><input type="number" name="zeit" id="zeit"><br>
    <label for="strecke">gefahrene Strecke (in km): </label><input type="number" name="strecke" id="strecke"><br>
    <label>Material: </label>
    <div id="mat">
      <div name="mat">
        <label for="matName">Name Material: </label><input type="text" name="matName" id="matName"><br>
        <label for="matAnz">Anzahl Material: </label><input type="number" name="matAnz" id="matAnz"><br>
        <label for="matPreis">Preis pro stück Material(in CHF): </label><input type="number" name="matPreis" id="matPreis"><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="handleAddMat()">+</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()">Senden</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're not creating any dynamic names. The names of the elements that you add are the same each time: `matName`, `matAnz`, and `matPreis`

Comment: The div is a new one every time nameMat.value = "mat" + realNumber;

Comment: BTW you don't need to use all that `createAttribute` stuff. You can just do `input1.type = "text"` and `input1.name = "matName"`

Comment: Give all the DIVs a class like `mat.class="mat"`. Then you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("mat")` to get all of them, and loop over them.

Comment: But if I want to make the loop get `mat1` and `mat2`, how would i do that?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < realNumber; i++) { let matid = "mat" + i; let div = document.getElementById(matid); ...}`

Comment: Thx! As always people on stack overflow are very helpfull!

Comment: How were you able to write all that code and you can't figure out a simple `for` loop like that?

Comment: Honestly i was just stupid and tired